# signal SIGABRT in segue from button

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, sigabrt

I have a problem. I made a segue from button to view controller and I get this error. I have been finding for 4 hours, but here is similar problems, not as mine.

[This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32e6E.png)
[image]
[This is description from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic15a.png)
[image]

Comment: The segue seems to be connected to the `Test` view controller directly. Try reconnecting the segue to the navigation controller in which `Test` is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could rewrite the prepare method to meet this snippets it's better than the one you are using

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "MySegueId" {
    if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? NextViewController {
            nextViewController.valueOfxyz = "XYZ" //Or pass any values
                                                                         }
                                    }
}
```